# How to use random matrix in fragment shader in samsung android devices?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, gpu, fragment-shader, mali

I am new to OpenGL. Below is the fragment shader code i am using for rendering but in all Samsung devices it shows only red color and in Nexus 4 & 5 it gives correct result. There is no linking error, even if i simply initialize matrix without using, it gives red color.

I searched and found there is some issue with Mali GPU. How can I define a random matrix and use that matrix in fragment shader code so that it gives me correct result on all platforms.

```
        fragmentShaderCode5 = 
        "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external :  require\n"
        + "precision lowp float;"
        + "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;"
        + " mat4 colorMatrix;"
        + "uniform samplerExternalOES texture;"
        + "void main()\n {"
        + " mat4 colorMatrix = mat4(0.3588f, 0.7044f, 0.1368f, 0f,            
          0.2990f,0.5870f, 0.1140f, 0f, 0.2392f, 0.4696f, 0.0912f ,0f, 
          0f,0f,0f,0f);"
        + " vec4 color = texture2D(texture, v_TexCoordinate);"
        + " vec4 outputColor = color*colorMatrix ;"
        + " gl_FragColor =  (0.1 * color) + ((1.0 - 0.1) * 
          outputColor);"
        + "}";
```

Comment: I solved this defining outside , earlier i was trying same but i was not defining correctly (uniform and verying).

Comment: But if any one can give me some reason for this it will be very helpful.

Comment: I would guess you are hitting a fp precision problem; Mali treats lowp and mediump as fp16 as it is more energy efficient, whereas many other platforms treat it as fp32. On the Mali-T600/700/800 series the fragment shaders support highp which might help (but it's not available on Mali-300/400/450 as they are OpenES 2.0 only parts, and highp is not a requirement for OpenGL ES 2.0 fragment shaders).


I would also add that doing a matrix multiply in every fragment is expensive ... if you're going to be using this more than once bake it into the texture and just load that pre-converted.